# Secure two separate java applications with one spring security

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I have been looking for quite awhile for solution to have one spring security for 2 or more applications.

Basically I have a main app (`/`) running on tomcat, where the user can interact with it etc, and second one, in separate a context (`/player`).

I want to use one spring security to secure both app. So when user will login to main app (`/`) will be also able to access another context.

This is the point where I got stuck. If anyone has any idea how to set it up, that would be more then great.

Comment: What you need is a single-sign-on solution. There is one for Spring Security and another one for Tomcat (valve).

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you can use security for two contexts, if they are part of one application only. Means, both are deployed with one war itself.

If two applications are deployed with separate wars - I do not think that you can use single security context.

A basic [example](http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/31/spring-security-3-hello-world-example) (& some google) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you should try single sign with spring security
http://www.disasterarea.co.uk/blog/saml-based-single-sign-on-sso-in-spring-security-applications/